# Proper azure keyvault configuration

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-rm-template, azure-appservice, azure-deployment

I have a simple `az cli` command that works for me:

```
az keyvault create -l $location -n $name -g $groupName --enabled-for-deployment true
```

additionally I set azure env variables in this way:

```
az webapp config appsettings set --resource-group $groupName \
      --name $webAppName \
      --settings AZURE_TENANT_ID='..' AZURE_CLIENT_ID='..' AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET='..'
```

so this code works for me:

```
var client = new SecretClient(
            new Uri($"https://{name}.vault.azure.net/"), 
            new DefaultAzureCredential(),
            options);
client.SetSecretAsync(new KeyVaultSecret("key", "value"));
```

Now, I want to replace the above `az keyvault create ..` command on ARM template and this command (the rest configuration is the same):

```
az deployment group create --resource-group $groupName \
--template-file $armTemplatePath \
--parameters $armTemplateParams \
--parameters name=$name \
--parameters tenant=${{ secrets.DEPLOYMENT_AZURE_TENANT_ID }}
```

where ARM template (taken from azure portal) looks like:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "sku": {
            "type": "string"  => Standard
        },
        "accessPolicies": {
            "type": "array"   => []
        },
        "tenant": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "enabledForDeployment": {
            "type": "bool"    => true
        },
        "enabledForTemplateDeployment": {
            "type": "bool"    => false
        },
        "enabledForDiskEncryption": {
            "type": "bool"    => false
        },
        "enableRbacAuthorization": {
            "type": "bool"    => tried true and false
        },
        "publicNetworkAccess": {
            "type": "string" => true 
        },
        "enableSoftDelete": {
            "type": "bool" => true
        },
        "softDeleteRetentionInDays": {
            "type": "int"  => 90
        },
        "networkAcls": {
            "type": "object" =>
                                         "value": {
                                                  "defaultAction": "allow",
                                                  "bypass": "AzureServices",
                                                  "ipRules": [],
                                                  "virtualNetworkRules": []
                                                   }


        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2021-10-01",
            "name": "[parameters('name')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
            "properties": {
                "enabledForDeployment": "[parameters('enabledForDeployment')]",
                "enabledForTemplateDeployment": "[parameters('enabledForTemplateDeployment')]",
                "enabledForDiskEncryption": "[parameters('enabledForDiskEncryption')]",
                "enableRbacAuthorization": "[parameters('enableRbacAuthorization')]",
                "accessPolicies": "[parameters('accessPolicies')]",
                "tenantId": "[parameters('tenant')]",
                "sku": {
                    "name": "[parameters('sku')]",
                    "family": "A"
                },
                "publicNetworkAccess": "[parameters('publicNetworkAccess')]",
                "enableSoftDelete": "[parameters('enableSoftDelete')]",
                "softDeleteRetentionInDays": "[parameters('softDeleteRetentionInDays')]",
                "networkAcls": "[parameters('networkAcls')]"
            },
            "tags": {},
            "dependsOn": []
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {}
}
```

This configuration is deployed correctly, but when I want to query it as I did previously, I catch this error:

```
    Azure.RequestFailedException: The user, group or application 'appid=..;oid=..;iss=https://sts.windows.net/../' does not have secrets set permission on key vault '%KeyVaultName%;location=eastus'. For help resolving this issue, please see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=..
    Status: 403 (Forbidden)
    ErrorCode: Forbidden
```

It would be good to know what is the difference between 2 these approaches and what I missed and where can it be configured. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> It would be good to know what is the difference between 2 these approaches and what I missed and where can it be configured. Any help appreciated.

If you create an `Azure Key Vault` using `Azure CLI`, the default permission model will be set as `'Vault Access Policy'` with full permissions. This allows you to access the `Key Vault's` keys and secrets.

**Keyvault Creation Using Azure CLI**

[image]

If you create a `Key Vault` using an `ARM` Template, the default setting will be Azure role-based access control  unless you specify a `Vault Configuration` in the `ARM Template`. In your JSON code, you have used the **'enableRbacAuthorization'** property. To access the Key Vault's keys and secrets, you will need an `RBAC` role such as the `Key Vault Administrator` role. This role allows you to perform all data plane operations on the `Key Vault` and its objects, including certificates, keys, and secrets. However, it does not grant permission to manage `Key Vault` resources or manage role assignments.

**Keyvault Creation with ARM Template.**

[image]

To resolve the below error, kindly assign the `Key Vault Administrator` role to the user

```
Azure.RequestFailedException: The user, group or application 'appid=..;oid=..;iss=https://sts.windows.net/../' does not have secrets set permission on key vault '%KeyVaultName%;location=eastus'. For help resolving this issue, please see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=..
    Status: 403 (Forbidden)
    ErrorCode: Forbidden
```

Assign `Key Vault Administrator` Role to user as below.

[image]

Once the `RBAC` role is assigned, the user is able to access the keys and secrets

[image]

Comment: thanks, I will check it. Just a note, I used `enableRbacAuthorization` with both values `false` and `true` and both approaches failed

Comment: Kindly assign Key Vault Administrator role to user, if you are using enableRbacAuthorization method.

Comment: yeah, I got idea, but just to clarify, am I right that you're saying that I use `enableRbacAuthorization method` in both cases when `enableRbacAuthorization` is `true` and `false`? I would expect that if I set `enableRbacAuthorization` to false, i don't use such method?

Comment: If you set the enableRbacAuthorization property to false in ARM template, it means that RBAC authorization will be disabled for the Key Vault. you will be able to access the Key Vault's secrets without any additional RBAC role assignments ,check the access configuration option in Portal once create a Key vault.